# How to resolve Json Error: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

**pls correction with correct syntax**
**pythoh piece of Code that cause error:**

```
def reliable_send(self, data):
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        self.connection.send(json_data)
```

**Error is:**

self.connection.send(json_data) at **json_data** whic is

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to encode the data before sending, this should be the solution

```
def reliable_send(self, data):
    json_data = json.dumps(data)
    self.connection.send(json_data.encode())
```